# Python3.4 in bash (Linux) isn't giving text coloring

Tags: python, linux, bash, text-coloring

I am using Python 3.4 on Debian 7. I downloaded the Python3.4 source (Python-3.4.1.tgz) package, compiled and installed it. Now, when i am using the Python3.4 interpreter, the text coloring for the codes isn't happening/working.

This is a let down as the coloring helps in code readability. When i use Python IDLE, text coloring works.  Any help on how to turn back the syntax coloring for Python3.4 interpreter?

Thanks!

Comment: The Python interactive interpreter doesn't support syntax highlighting. Use IDLE or another IDE for that; you could perhaps use [`ipython`](http://ipython.org/) for (limited) syntax highlighting in of already-written Python code with the `??` operator.

Comment: Thanks Martijn for the quick response!

Comment: There's also [bpython](http://bpython-interpreter.org/), which I know some people like.  It supports highlighting.

Answer (score 1):

The Python interactive shell does not support syntax highlighting, no. IDLE is still shipped with Python 3.4, use that if you liked it before.

You can install an alternative interactive shell; there are several to choose from:

- [dreampie](http://www.dreampie.org/) (integrates matplotlib as well)
- [bpython](http://bpython-interpreter.org/), shows inline documentation and argument suggestions as you type
- [ipython](http://ipython.org/), does *not* syntax highlight inline but can show object source code with the `??identifier` syntax. Otherwise very powerful and versatile.

Or install a decent code editor or IDE.

Comment: Thanks DSM and Martijn for your replies!